# Routing is not working when page redirect to same page with different querystring

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

On app.component.ts i have a search autocomplete control when i search employee and it redirects employee detail page.but if i search from employee detail page for another employee, page doesn't load because of routing path is same and only querystring value is changed.

when i call below url ,it works fine.

http://myapp.com/employee/33

but when i search employee from employeedetail page ,page doesn't load with new values.

```js
const routes: RouterConfig = [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      {path: 'employee/:id', component:employeedetails}
    ];
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

how do you load the employees details? are you subscribed to router changes? if you are not, then it won't change..
something like this

```
      ngOnInit(){
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
              this.id = params['id'];
        }
        //get employee details with id
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes !! i got solution for this.
In Angular when we call same route path from same page but parameters different,it treat as same page so because of security reason it will not redirect.

> On route File

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      {path: 'employee/:id', component:employeedetails},
 {path: 'employee/a/:id', component:employeedetails}
    ];
```

> on Component File:-

```
 if (window.location.href.indexOf("employee/a") > -1) {
                    this._pagePath = ['employee', Value]
                }
                else {
                    this._pagePath = ['employee/a', Value]
                }
```